# Evenly space yticks in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, plot

My code

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{filename.csv}
    Month,              Year,       Host-Count
    Jul,                1993,       1776000
    Jul,                1994,       3212000    
    Jul,                1995,       6642000    
    Jul,                1996,       12881000   
    Jul,                1997,       19540000   
    Jul,                1998,       36739000   
    Jul,                1999,       56218000   
    Jul,                2000,       93047785   
    Jul,                2001,       125888197  
    Jul,                2002,       162128493    
    Jan,                2003,       171638297    
    Jul,                2004,       285139107    
    Jul,                2005,       353284187    
    Jul,                2006,       439286364    
    Jul,                2007,       489774269    
    Jul,                2008,       570937778    
    Jul,                2009,       681064561    
    Jul,                2010,       768913036       
    Jul,                2011,       849869781    
    Jul,                2012,       908585739    
    Jul,                2013,       996230757    
    Jul,                2014,       1028544414      
    Jul,                2015,       1033836245      
    Jan,                2016,       1048766623      
    Jul,                2017,       1074971748      
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.76\linewidth}{!}{
            %           \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{Figures/HostsIncreaseICS.csv}\datatable
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            %------------X-Axis data and style---------------
            enlarge x limits=.01,
            xlabel={Year},
            xlabel near ticks,
            xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
            xtick=data,
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep ={} },
            %------------X-Axis data and style---------------
            ytick=data, 
            %-------------- Scaling ------------            
            scale only axis,
            log ticks with fixed point,
            scaled ticks=false,
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            %------------grid---------------
            minor tick num=3,   
            grid=both,
            grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
            major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
            ]

            \addplot +[smooth] table [col sep=comma, x=Year,y=Host-Count] {filename.csv};

            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }%end resizebox

    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

output: 
[image]

I want to fix the y-axis ticks. I also want to keep all data points as is. I don't want to use log base for the values. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe removing `ytick=data` is what you want to do? (I am not sure.)

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{filename.csv}
Month,              Year,       Host-Count
Jul,                1993,       1776000
Jul,                1994,       3212000    
Jul,                1995,       6642000    
Jul,                1996,       12881000   
Jul,                1997,       19540000   
Jul,                1998,       36739000   
Jul,                1999,       56218000   
Jul,                2000,       93047785   
Jul,                2001,       125888197  
Jul,                2002,       162128493    
Jan,                2003,       171638297    
Jul,                2004,       285139107    
Jul,                2005,       353284187    
Jul,                2006,       439286364    
Jul,                2007,       489774269    
Jul,                2008,       570937778    
Jul,                2009,       681064561    
Jul,                2010,       768913036       
Jul,                2011,       849869781    
Jul,                2012,       908585739    
Jul,                2013,       996230757    
Jul,                2014,       1028544414      
Jul,                2015,       1033836245      
Jan,                2016,       1048766623      
Jul,                2017,       1074971748      
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.76\linewidth}{!}{
        %           \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{Figures/HostsIncreaseICS.csv}\datatable
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        %------------X-Axis data and style---------------
        enlarge x limits=.01,
        xlabel={Year},
        xlabel near ticks,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
        xtick=data,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep ={} },
        %------------X-Axis data and style---------------
        %ytick=data,% <- remove this line
        %-------------- Scaling ------------            
        scale only axis,
        %log ticks with fixed point,
        scaled ticks=false,
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        %------------grid---------------
        minor tick num=3,   
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        ]

        \addplot +[smooth] table [col sep=comma, x=Year,y=Host-Count] {filename.csv};

        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%end resizebox

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

If you really want to use `ytick=data` and the distance between two consecutive ticks should not depend on the difference between the related y-values (that seems strange to me), then you have to use `y expr=\coordindex` for the plot and `yticklabels from table={filename.csv}{Host-Count},` in the `axis` settings. Additionally I would use `\scriptsize` for the tick labels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{filename.csv}
Month,              Year,       Host-Count
Jul,                1993,       1776000
Jul,                1994,       3212000    
Jul,                1995,       6642000    
Jul,                1996,       12881000   
Jul,                1997,       19540000   
Jul,                1998,       36739000   
Jul,                1999,       56218000   
Jul,                2000,       93047785   
Jul,                2001,       125888197  
Jul,                2002,       162128493    
Jan,                2003,       171638297    
Jul,                2004,       285139107    
Jul,                2005,       353284187    
Jul,                2006,       439286364    
Jul,                2007,       489774269    
Jul,                2008,       570937778    
Jul,                2009,       681064561    
Jul,                2010,       768913036       
Jul,                2011,       849869781    
Jul,                2012,       908585739    
Jul,                2013,       996230757    
Jul,                2014,       1028544414      
Jul,                2015,       1033836245      
Jan,                2016,       1048766623      
Jul,                2017,       1074971748      
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.76\linewidth}{!}{
        %           \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{Figures/HostsIncreaseICS.csv}\datatable
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        %------------X-Axis data and style---------------
        enlarge x limits=.01,
        xlabel={Year},
        xlabel near ticks,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
        xtick=data,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep ={} },
        %------------X-Axis data and style---------------
        ytick=data,
        yticklabels from table={filename.csv}{Host-Count},% <- added
        tick label style={font=\scriptsize},% <- added
        %-------------- Scaling ------------            
        scale only axis,
        %log ticks with fixed point,
        scaled ticks=false,
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        %------------grid---------------
        minor tick num=3,
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        ]

        \addplot +[smooth] table [col sep=comma, x=Year,
            y expr=\coordindex% <- changed
            ] {filename.csv};

        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%end resizebox

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still i need the yticks to display all my data points.

Comment: @Sari Should there be the same distance between the ticks of  y=1776000 and y=3212000 and the ticks of y=570937778 and y=681064561? So should the distance between two consecutive ticks not depend on the difference between the related y-values?

Comment: yes exactly this is what am trying to do

Comment: That seems strange to me, but see my updated answer.